# Wait until Download dialog box appears in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a script which is downloading excel from URL automatically. The problem which I am facing is that the time after which dialog box appears is not fixed so I cannot hard code the wait time.
I need a code which will wait until the dialog box appears and then click on Save As button.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Do Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262728(v=vs.60).aspx)?

Comment: Please show the code you're trying to use already. Without showing your code, it is hard to suggest an appropriate resolution to what may be a very specific problem.

Comment: this may be useful, or it may not be (it's hard for me to know, since I don't know what you've already tried...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651257/how-can-i-automate-the-download-dialog-box-in-ie-using-vba?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking time and answering my question.

I finally find out how to work on this. I used the below code.

```
Dim website
website = "http://yoursite.com"
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate website
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Cells(1, 1) = GetTitle
var = CheckTitle(Cells(1, 1))
Do While var = False
    Cells(1, 1) = GetTitle
    var = CheckTitle(Cells(1, 1))
Loop
Cells(1, 1) = ""
```

Function GetTitle()

```
Dim ActiveWindowHandle As Long
'get the handle of the active window
ActiveWindowHandle = GetForegroundWindow()

Dim Title As String * 255

' get the title of the active window
GetWindowText ActiveWindowHandle, Title, Len(Title)
'MsgBox myString
GetTitle = Trim(Title)
```

End Function

Function CheckTitle(checkval As String) As Boolean

```
If checkval <> "Internet Explorer" Then
    CheckTitle = False
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:0:10"))
Else
    CheckTitle = True
End If
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of dialog box you are referring to, but here are a couple scripts that will download files from the web.

Put this in cell A1:
http://www.math.smith.edu/r/data/help.xlsx

Put this in cell B1:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\ or the path where you want to download the file to

Put this in cell C1:
File download successfully!

Run this code.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Sub pMain()
  Dim sURL As String
  Dim sDestination As String
  Dim bSuccess As Boolean
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim strSavePath As String
  Dim URL As String, ext As String
  Dim buf, ret As Long

  'Change to suit
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  With ws
    For lRow = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      sURL = .Cells(lRow, "A")
      sDestination = .Cells(lRow, "B")

      buf = Split(sURL, ".")
      ext = buf(UBound(buf))

        pos = InStrRev(sURL, "/", -1)
        file = Mid(sURL, pos + 1, 99)
        strSavePath = sDestination & file
        ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, sURL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
            If ret = 0 Then
                .Cells(lRow, "C") = "File download successfully!"
            Else
                .Cells(lRow, "C") = "Couldn't download the file!"
            End If

      DoEvents
    Next lRow
  End With
End Sub
```

Also, try this...

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

```
Sub DownloadFilefromWeb()
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim URL As String, ext As String
    Dim buf, ret As Long
    URL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    buf = Split(URL, ".")
    ext = buf(UBound(buf))
    strSavePath = "C:\Users\your_path\Desktop\" & "DownloadedFile." & ext
    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
    If ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Download has been succeed!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply

Comment: Dim website
    website = "http://gcm-perceive.nam.nsroot.net/qtv/report_contents.jsp?report-id=31&ver=1&node-id=" & server & "&c=0&sd=" & fDate & "&ed=" & lDate & "&theme-id=portal&r=excel"
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate website
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
          Loop
    End With

Comment: I am using this code to open webpage which will start processing. Once the processing gets completed the download dialog box will appear. I am able to handle the dialog box using SendKeys.

Comment: The time for processing here is not fixed, it depends upon the size of the excel workbook to be downloaded. That's why I cannot hard code the waiting time and wait until the dialog box appears and then do further proceedings.

Comment: The URL mentioned here is on client network and I guess you won't be able to reach it.